# What is a strategy from moving from home grown forms authentication to AD?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, forms-authentication

The question says it all. Our application is currently authenticating users against a database. We have a mix of internal and external users. For new internal applications we would like to move to AD for internal users, and in the future we would like to set up a service that allows external users to register on the site, but have the registration code create an AD user that has rights based on the URL that they are hitting. Our scheme is [customername].company.com. What are some recommendations? Have you gone through this experience?

Edit: This is a mix of webforms and mvc. .NET 4.0

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET/web apps, or for WinForms - or both?? What version of the .NET framework are you on??

Comment: @marc_s Updated to reflect platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// validate username/password credentials against AD
if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password))
{
   // do something
}

// getting current user and testing against group membership
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity("YourGroup");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
{
   // do something
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

If you're using mostly ASP.NET apps, I would recommend checking into the ASP.NET membership and role providers, which have an interface to AD, so that you can use AD groups (and user's membership in those groups) as criteria for allowing/disallowing certain functions.

See some blog posts on the topic:

- [Active Directory and the ASP.NET 2.0 membership provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2005/08/17/452905.aspx)
- [ASP.NET 2.0 Membership, Roles, Forms Authentication, and Security Resources](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx)
- [Membership and Role Providers in ASP.NET 2.0 Part I](http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx)

Comment: How would I deal with users hitting companyA.company.com vs companyB.company.com?

Comment: Are those separate AD domains? Are they part of the same AD forest, and is there a mutual and two-way trust between those domains??

Comment: @marc_s They are not sub-domains today. In fact today the site is one vdir and we make configuration decisions based on the [customer] in [customer].company.com. The actual AD structure is not setup, so the AD configuration is wide open for best practices.

Comment: @TheHurt: where would those AD accounts for the external users reside? In the same AD domain as your internal users (just in a separate OU or container)? For external users, you might need to create a domain context with a specific user/pwd that has permissions to do stuff in, and you can limit your domain context to a sub-container/sub-OU with another overloaded constructor (e.g. limit your domain context for external users to `OU=ExternalUsers,DC=YourCompany,DC=com`)

Comment: @marc_s Yeah I think we would have one domain (or sub-domains for each data center that have a trust with the master domain). The initial thought is we would have a service that impersonates a user that is able to create users, but only that service would have the rights.

Comment: @TheHurt: yes, that would probably be a really good approach, too - hide all things AD related behind a service facade. Then only that single service needs to know anything about AD and it could handle (and hide) the differences between internal and external users